# How to move the "Show Applications" icon to the left?

Tags: 20.04

It confuses my brain and doesn't feel natural with it on the right and it pisses me off a lil. Please help! (I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Comment: Do you have your dock at the bottom of the screen not on the left edge?

Comment: i have it on the bottom of the screen

Comment: @WU-TANG's answer will resolve your issue, then.

Answer (score 5):

In a terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true`

Comment: do i restart my laptop after typing this

Comment: it say unknown command and then comes up with a bunch of stuff for the command "gsettings"

Comment: my bad... i left off "set".... see edit